# Laravel Не работает две формы на странице

Tags: php, laravel

Суть проблемы в следующем:
Есть два роута ведущие на одну страницу (это будет Landing Page с двумя формами обратной связи **(1. Номер телефона 2. Обратная связь)**).

**Сами по себе формы работают**, но как я в web.php добавляю новый роут, то по итогу получаю ошибку `Route [fb.send.phone] not defined.`
Если поменять местами fb.send.phone и fb.send.message то ошибка меняется на `Route [fb.send.message] not defined.`

Файл **web.php**

```php
Route::GET('/',  [MainController::class, 'indexPage')
   ->name('main.page'); //Главная страница сайта
Route::POST('/', [MainController::class, 'sendMessage')
   ->name('fb.send.message'); // Форма отправки сообщение из формы обратной связи
Route::POST('/', [MainController::class, 'sendPhone')
   ->name('fb.send.phone'); // Форма отправки номера телефона
```

Как решить данную проблему? чтобы не было в последующем проблем с добавлением форм на одну страницу сайта?

Comment: нельзя делать два одинаковых маршрута. Сделайте разные названия и всё, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что ваш uri дублируется и перезаписывается. Сделайте вот так.

`Route::POST('/message', [MainController::class, 'sendMessage')->name('fb.send.message');  Route::POST('/phone', [MainController::class, 'sendPhone')->name('fb.send.phone');`